# how do you specify cppcheck parameters in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cppcheck

how do you specify cppcheck parameters in jenkins?

I can see from the console output that the following is being run:

`+ cppcheck --output-file=cppcheck.xml --enable=all --inconclusive --xml --xml-version=2 ../`

I don't know where the cppcheck parameters are specified

Comment: The question is quite unspecific. What exactly do you want to do? Did you write some kind of Jenkinsfile or a pipeline yet?

Comment: there is a jenkins pipeline that includes cppcheck, which runs with default parameters

Comment: It always helps to provide some code or at least the code snippet that is related to your question.

Comment: what code would you like to see?